# Windows Phone 8 App Certification Requirements

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

There are a couple of posts quoting Microsoft saying:

> The app must first describe the notifications to be provided and
>   obtain the user’s express permission (opt-in), and must provide a
>   mechanism through which the user can opt out of receiving push
>   notifications.

I have searched the net for this and cant' find this anywhere on the Microsoft site.  All I have found is the following:

> Your app must respect system settings for notifications and remain
>   functional when they are disabled. This includes the presentation of
>   ads and notifications to the customer, which must also be consistent
>   with the customer’s preferences, whether the notifications are
>   provided by the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS), Windows
>   Push Notification Service (WNS) or any other service. If the customer
>   disables notifications, either on an app-specific or system-wide
>   basis, your app must remain functional.

So it seems the may have relaxed the requirement.  Currently the first thing our app asks when its first launched is "Would you like to received push notifications"  in an message box.  This hurts user experience so we were wondering if we can just leave the "opt-out" on the settings page.

Does anybody know if this requirement has been relaxed so that we don't have to explicitly ask it up front?

Comment: From personal experience: You can just activate push notifcations by default. Submitted multiple apps and they are still in the store. And I've seen multiple apps do the same thing. Personally I'd make it depend on the scenario: If the notifications are a usefull part of your app (car has arrived, etc.), it's ok, to leave them on. If it is just news, I'd ask for permission. Or at least show a small toast: "Notifications activated, click here for settings."

Comment: Thanks Kai, this is the route I'm hoping to follow.

Answer (score 0):

you must let the user to decide to set the notification on the first run of your app, and also create a section in the settings page that let the user to set it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we've currently implemented our app:  Ask first, but also let the user change it later.  However,  Can you find me any official Microsoft documentation that says so?

Comment: Not really, that's just an unwritten rule for the UX of WP.

Comment: I seriously doubt Microsoft will leave any certification rules as "unwritten" and then fail your app because of it.  How are people supposed to guess what the certification rules are if they are "unwritten".

Comment: @RogerW , you where right about the unwritten rule I said before. In http://bit.ly/1MOCcr9 says: "Your app must respect system settings for notifications and remain functional when they are disabled... If the customer disables notifications, either on an app-specific or system-wide basis, your app must remain functional." There you will find other requirements about WP App Certification by looking at http://bit.ly/18hqLc5